# EF6 + Migrations + SqlServer/SqlCe4

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-migrations

I had a solution with EF5+Migrations targeting dual databases SqlServer/SqlCe4.
I have a switch in code to set appropriate connections.
It all worked fine.

But now I wanted some features of EF6 so I upgraded.
Initially it worked with SqlServer but I had major issues with SqlCe.
Error: "The specified table already exists. [ TableName ]"

Now it does not work with any of them:
"The specified index already exists. [ IX_TableNameId ]"

Connections are created in a factory:

```
public static class ContextFactory
{
    static ContextFactory()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SongServiceDataContext, SongServiceConfiguration>());
    }

    public static SongServiceDataContext GetClientContext()
    {
        // Get path
        var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LocalDbPath"];

        // Create SqlCe connection
        var sb = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = path };
        var con = new SqlCeConnection(sb.ToString());

        return new SongServiceDataContext(con);
    }

    public static SongServiceDataContext GetServerContext()
    {
        // Get connectionstring
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerConnectionString"];
        if (!connectionString.IsSpecified())
            throw new Exception("AppSetting 'ServerConnectionString' must be specified in config file");

        // Create SqlServer connection
        var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        var con = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());

        return new SongServiceDataContext(con);
    }
}
```

I decided to delete databases and restart migrations with an initial create.
Add-Migration InitalModel -ProjectName: "MyApp.Business"
That causes the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'v11.0' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.<GetService>b__0(ArgumentException e, String n)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String nameOrConnectionString)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name, Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'v11.0' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.
```

It looks like a configuration error so I checked the App.config of the specified project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to change everything so I am now slightly frustrated.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look like your localdb installtion is broken, try to reinstall it

Comment: I can't remember that I ever installed localdb. Will it be part of some other installation (SQL Server, VS2013, SQLCe4, ...)?
Do I really need it? I have SQL Server and SqlCe4 installed. My intention with the ContextFactory was to use either of those. Should I modify the config in order to make the migration generation use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error Entity Framework messages were very misleading. The main problem was actually more on the context creation side. In my context class I had two constructors, one initialized with connection and one parameter less:

```
public MyDataContext(DbConnection conn): base(conn, true)
{
}

public MyDataContext()
{
}
```

I finally realized that even if I didn't call the parameter less constructor it was actually called several times by the migration. This causing a lot of confusion ...

As I understand it the proper way now to direct the migration in the right way is to let the context factory implement IDbContextFactory. I tried to call specific methods for creating each context but the migration was still calling the IDbContextFactory Create method behind the scenes. I didn't figure out a robust way of deciding what context to be called.

In my situation it is actually fine to have a global switch, as each calling assembly is always using the same context. So I decided to set a static property on the factory class. It is set on application startup and will then direct the creation in the right direction.

```
public class ContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<MyDataContext>
{
    public static DbSource DefaultDbSource = DbSource.Client;

    static ContextFactory()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<SongServiceDataContext, SongServiceConfiguration>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called by the migration.
    /// </summary>
    public MyDataContext Create()
    {
        return GetContext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is added for my convenience.
    /// </summary>
    public static MyDataContext GetContext()
    {
        return DefaultDbSource == DbSource.Client ? GetClientContext() : GetServerContext();
    }


    #region Private Methods

    private static MyDataContext GetClientContext()
    {
        // Get path
        var dirDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var dirData = Path.Combine(dirDocuments, "MyApplication", "Data");
        if (!Directory.Exists(dirData))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(dirData);
        var path = Path.Combine(dirData, "MyApplicationData.sdf");

        // Create SqlCe connection
        var sb = new SqlCeConnectionStringBuilder {DataSource = path};
        var con = new SqlCeConnection(sb.ToString());

        return new MyDataContext(con);
    }

    private static MyDataContext GetServerContext()
    {
        // Get connectionstring
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerConnectionString"];
        if (!connectionString.IsSpecified())
            throw new Exception("AppSetting 'ServerConnectionString' must be specified in config file");

        // Create SqlServer connection
        var sb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        var con = new SqlConnection(sb.ToString());

        return new SongServiceDataContext(con);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Tip: Even after I settled with this factory setup I had some problems. The migration went fine, but every connection after that caused all sorts of weird problems. I struggled hours and was close to giving up. A simple clean and rebuild of my solution did the final trick! It seems that remnant files must have caused some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The section:

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
```

Is completely broken, and several secitions for SQLCE are missing from the config file.

Create a new empty console app, and install EntityyFramework.SqlServerCompact package to get the correct config settings

Comment: Thanks Erik, a simple and good advice! Now I was able to run migration generation again. But when I actually call the databases the same confusing error keeps coming up again: "The specified table already exists. [ ObjectName ]". I get the same message for SqlCe and SqlServer.  Neither client nor server database are generated. The datamodel should be OK, as it worked fine before the upgrade to EF6 ....